# What is the probability that the testing procedure ends at 12th testing?

Tags: probability

> A lot contains $20$ articles.The probability that the lot contains
>   exactly contains exactly $2$ defective articles is $0.4$ and that the lot
>   contains exactly $3$ defective articles is $0.6$.Articles are drawn from
>   the lot at random without replacement and tested till all defective
>   articles are found.

What is the probability that the testing procedure ends at $12$th testing$?$

I thought of making two cases- $0.4$ and $0.6$.But then I'm stuck.Help please!

Comment: Hint:  say you knew there were exactly $2$.  There are $\binom {20}{2}=190$ equally likely pairs amongst your articles, of which exactly $11$ have largest element $12$.

Comment: http://www.askiitians.com/forums/Algebra/a-lot-contains-20-articles-the-probability-that-t_104336.htm i got something here...can you tell me why is it multiplied with the (1/9) term ?

Comment: How many articles are there from $12_{th}$ onwards (inclusive) ?

Comment: This is a weird problem. Someone testing does not know how many defectives there are. So you can never stop after having found two defectives.

Comment: The $\frac 19$ is the probability that one article is defective after you have removed $11$ articles (and found exactly one defective one in the list).  I think this is a somewhat inefficient way to do the count but it does, correctly, give $\frac {11}{190}$.  I agree with the other comment that the problem is ill-posed in that the tester can't stop at $12$ having only found two defective units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this
[image]

The testing ends at 12th item implies 12th item is defective. Therefore creating sample space by selecting 11items tested before 12th item. In first case when probability of having two defective items is two we have one defective item and 10 non defective item in first 11 items tested. I have written probability for same. After that probability of 12th item being defective is 1/9. Similarly done for other.
Hope this Helps!